# How to write rails model to process dependent fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with checkbox that enables/disables another field:

```
<%= check_box_tag :enable %>
<%= text_input_tag :extra_parameter %>
```

The model will store the extra parameter if enable is true. With _tag I will need to pass the extra parameters from the controller to the model.

Is there a way to do this using form builder and have the logic completely in the model?

View:

```
<%= f.check_box :enable %>
<%= f.text_input :extra_parameter %>
```

Model:

```
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def enable=
     ????
  end

  def extra_parameter=
     self.extra_parameter = true if ???
  end
end
```

One way is instance variable - but this presumes the model 'enable' will be called before 'extra_parameter'. Is this the best way? is there alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do this by overriding the `initialize` method in order to be able to do something like this in your controller and have it just work:

```
ExampleModel.new(:extra_params => "Hello world", :enabled => true)
```

Your model would look something like the below, which overrides initialize, calling `super` first to set any accessible attributes, and then setting `extra_params` using our custom setter. We need to do this in this order because, like you mentioned, we need to ensure that `enabled` is set and returns the correct boolean value when we decide whether or not to set `extra_params`.

```
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(attrs={})
    super(attrs)
    self.extra_params = attrs.fetch(:extra_params, nil)
  end

  def extra_params=(value)
    self[:extra_params] = value if enabled?
  end
end
```

With this method, the order that you set the parameters in when new-ing up the object shouldn't matter.

Comment: Great solution for having the order not matter

Answer (score 0):

For attributes that don't have an equivalent column in the databas, you can use [attr_accessor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000478):

```
attr_accessor :enable

def extra_parameter=(value)
    self[:extra_parameter] = value if enable
end
```

As long as "enable" is passed before "extra_parameter" in a mass assignment, this will work. I'm not sure if that order can be enforced, though.